# I wanted to create a simple login page using Django frame work , I got this error while connecting between html pages can someone look into it

Tags: post, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, http-post

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SlmI.png)<--This in screenshot of error i'm getting
this is the code of both html page and python function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1> Signin</h1>
        <form action="/signin" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <label for="">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your Username" required>
            <br>
            <label for="">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass1" name="pass1" placeholder="Enter your Password" required>
            <br>


            <button type="submit">Sign in</button>


        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        pass1 = request.POST["pass1"]

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=pass1)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            fname = user.first_name
            return render(request, "authentication/index.html", {fname: "fame"})
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Wrong Credentials")
            return redirect("home")

    return render(request, "authentication/signin.html")
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.home, name="home"),
    path("signup/", views.signup, name="signup"),
    path("signin/", views.signin, name="signin"),
    path("signout/", views.signout, name="signout"),
]
```

Im trying to create a simple login page in Django,[screenshot of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QkJ8.png) i'm expecting to solve the error in the image

Comment: i have tried writing this line in my Django settings.py file # APPEND_SLASH = False

Answer (score 0):

I think it's very well explained in your error. You need to append a slash to your form action:

```html
<form action="/signin/" method="post">
```

OR, since you're rendering the form on the same URL where the form is POST-ed, you can simply omit the action (which is kind of easier to reuse):

```html
<form action="" method="post">
```